# Would see someone [do vs doing] something

Tags: expressions, tenses

I remember seeing an expression along the lines of "An act that would see him X"
For instance:

1. "The chess player prepared to make the move that would see him [win/winning] the game."
2. "He insulted the man in an act that would see him [dead/die]."
3. "The general ordered his men to perform a manouevre that would see the battle won."

Since I couldn't find anything about this on google (every question I've seen has been related to verb tenses), I'm beginning to doubt whether this expression even exists. If it does though:

1. When the expression refers to a person's state, which is correct? A simple present verb or an adjective?
2. When it refers to something passively, which is correct? A simple present or a progressive verb?
3. Are any of the above three sentences incorrect?

Comment: Yes; this usage is hard to find in dictionaries. 'The X that saw/would see Y V/Ving' usually means 'the X that ensured that Y Ved/would V' or 'the X that resulted in Y Ving etc'.  From the internet, 'a deal ... that would see him miss games'.  In your last example, 'that would see them win' becomes 'that would see the battle won', corresponding to 'that would ensure that the battle was won'. This sense of 'see' also occurs in constructions like 'See [to it] [that] it [gets] done!' and 'see it through'.

Comment: I think ***win*** and ***winning*** in #1 are unmarked infinitive and gerund, not simple present verb and adjective.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I actually meant for the first question to correspond to the second example and vice versa, don't ask why. Still, thank you for pointing this out, since my guess of simple present vs. progressive still wouldn't have been correct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you very much! So if I understand this correctly, pretty much all of the combinations you listed are correct, so long as I'm consistent? Or, going by your "would see him miss games" example, can one just mix and match the tenses?

Comment: Yes, I think there's quite a bit of possible variation in these structures. Look up strings (contained by double inverted commas) such as "action that would see", "strategy that would see", "something that would see"; the satellite (arguably a DO in all cases) following _see_ can be a NP (an increase in the number of immigrants), N + V-ing (+ ...), N + inf (+ ...), or passive N + V-ed (or N + being/getting//becoming [non-passive in this case] V-ed).

Comment: In his book "Quotes that Will Change Your Life" Russ Kick writes, "... There was a pause. I could see him _processing_. ..." (italics are mine). So, it appears that in the case of your first question, using the gerund in an adjectival sense is appropriate.